# Why circle in $R^3$ is a convex set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convex-analysis

I am reading a book and a chapter starts with the following statement:
"A circle in $R^3$ is an example of a convex set with an empty interior. If we 
restrict ourselves to the plane that contains it, however, the same circle now 
has a nonempty interior."
1) I don't understand why a circle in $R^3$ is a convex set. Because a circle is not a disc. Therefore, any line connecting two pOints will lie outside of the circle set.
2) Restricting to the plane means restricting the dimension to $R^2$? If yes, then the only case when it contains a circle is when a circle is $R^2$ and not $R^3$? How come now it has a non-empty interior?

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: I think he meant to say disk, becouse in a plane it has nonempty interior, and $S^1$ has empty interior in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Sounds as if the author is using "circle" to connote a disk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author means "disc" when s/he says "circle" in this context.

Comment: But how then a disc in $R^3$ has an empty interior?

Comment: An interior point here means in the topological sense, I guess, so a point around which you can find a small ball (an open neighbourhood) that is still inside the set. This is obviously impossible because any ball leaves the disc in the third dimension, so there are no interior points.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Thank you a lot